# How to find out which tables are most accessed or frequently used in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2005, optimization

I am currently in a situation where I need to find out which tables are used frequently or the number of times in our application given a certain period of time. Lets say from some startDate to endDate.

The details I would like to get here are, the tableName and how many times it was accessed.
Eg:-

```
tableName    No.Of Access
Table5        100
Table2         80
...
Tablen         n
```

Also if the above query or if there is any other way to check which columns in these tables are frequently used would be wonderful. The idea behind this exercise is to properly index the columns in most used tables. But I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about the optimization too. So if you guys have any better alternatives to identify how to optimize on the above, that would also be great.

We are using SQL server 2005 and the application is running on .net framework 3.5 hosted on IIS.
If any further details are required, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I'm aware of with anything like this type of information is `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`

Edit: It turns out that more reliable information can be gained from

```
select * from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(db_id(),NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

The difference between what the two report is covered well [in this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20180410202012/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/17/Seeking-Without-Indexes.aspx).

Comment: This only gives index usage stats right? Not the table accesses?

Comment: @Sachin - If the table has a clusterd index then the table access is an index access. (`index_id = 1`). If the table is a heap then it still appears in that `dmv` but look for `index_id = 0`. But actually `select * from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(db_id(),NULL,NULL,NULL)` is better.

Comment: If I do not have any primary key defined nor indexes defined on table, then it will not appear right?

Comment: @Sachin - Yes it will appear as `indexid=0`

Answer (score 1):

The way I would tune a "poorly-performing" database is to first identify the problem queries, and then optimze them, rather than just trying to optimize everything all at one go.

You can use SQL Profiler to identify poorly performing queries. Depending on your system, track the appropriate RPC, SQL batch, T-SQL, or stored procedure events, filtering on events that take too long (I tend to start with > 5 seconds duration) or that perform too many reads (I start with 12800 reads, about 100MB). Track these for a suitable length of "prime time" system usage, and you'll get a sense of which parts of your database are performing poorly, and which are performing well (i.e. those that don't appear on the list).

Alternatively, ask your users (or yourself) which parts of the system are performing poorly, and check out the underlying queries.

Depending on the complexity of your system, proper indexing can be a bit of an art, as the strategy to optimize one query may degrade performance of another. You may go through several revisions before you find one that works well enough. (Which is why we call it "tuning".)

Comment: yes, I do agree with your answer, but we have done that one round of profiling cycle. Our problem now is that, with increasing data in DB, the queries are performing slower. Hence we believe indexing is the only way which will help us now. We might be wrong too, but we dont know yet.