# How to get updated record in last 3 hours in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Employee`. Somebody has updated a few records in the last 3 hrs. I want to get those record which were updated.
If possible, I want the diff between the previous and current record in `sql`.
I'd like an answer as a query.

Comment: what is your table structure? if you store something like `CreatedDate / UpdatedDate`, you can use the solution provided by Tim Schmelter

Comment: If you don't have auditing in place you aren't going to get the previous values. sql server does not have a native version control for rows.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee e
WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, e.UpdatedAt, GETDATE()) <= 3
```

Comment: You are considering UpdatedAt column in Employee. But i don't have any column which maintain updated time. I am thinking to get it from sql server internal time stamp.

Comment: @HemantMalpote: Then you need to add one. To quote from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344413/sqlserver-row-date-last-modified): _" The on-disk structure for a record, or page for that sake, does not contain any references to the time of the last update.... no such info is available at the record/row level."_ Consider that SQL-Server is made to store billions of records, why should it store informations that are probably never used?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any columns in the table with datatype Row version, then a timestamp value will be added automatically to each rows in your table. This column value will be modified at each time any operation performed on the particular row.Row Version is the Timestamp value for the rows.TIMESTAMP value of row(s) would be automatically updated if we UPDATE any value of row(s) in the table. New TIMESTAMP value will always be the next incremented value of the largest TIMESTAMP value exist among all rows in the table.To get the last updated , just query the latest 3 row version columns

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(EmployeeID int PRIMARY KEY, VerCol rowversion) ;
```